# Как реализовать "Читать далее" в Django?

Tags: python, django

Как реализовать "Читать далее" в Djnago? Допустим у меня есть огромный текст. Для среза слов есть фильтр truncatewords,знаю. Но если кто-то захочет прочитать далее,а текст слишком большой - нужна кнопка или ссылка которая покажет весь текст,но как это сделать я не понимаю. Подскажите пожалуйста!

View отвечающий за вывод статьи на сайте(НЕ СТАТЕЙ,а именно отдельной статьи)

```
class Post(View):
    def get(self,request,post_id):
        try:
            post = News.objects.get(id__iexact=post_id)
            comments = post.comment_set.all()
        except News.DoesNotExist:
            return render(request,'blog/DoesNotExist.html')   
        except Http404:
            raise HttpResponse('Такого поста нет')      
        return render(request,'blog/post.html',context={'post':post,'comments':comments})
```

Comment: Сделайте вьюху для просмотра всех статей с кратким описанием (как его формировать другой вопрос) и кнопку "Читать далее" которая будут отсылать к полной статье. Посмотрите подробнее про `ListView` (список статей) и `DetailView` (детальное отображение статьи). Если надо могу привести примеры реализации.

Comment: Гениальная идея(без сарказма),я подумаю над этим и возможно реализую это позже в других тестовых проектах.Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте во view, которое ответственно за показ страницы с текстом параметр `showFullText`. Если параметр не передан, то считайте, что он `False` и тогда делайте обрезание текста. В ссылке генерируйте URL на это же view з `showFullText=true`.

Если параметра `showFullText==true` то view должно показывать полный текст.

Это может выглядеть так:

```
def get(self,request,post_id):
        try:
            # если пареметр не передали то считаем что нужно обрезать
            showFullText = bool(request.GET.get('showFullText', 'False'))
            post = News.objects.get(id__iexact=post_id)
            comments = post.comment_set.all()
        except News.DoesNotExist:
            return render(request,'blog/DoesNotExist.html')   
        except Http404:
            raise HttpResponse('Такого поста нет')      
        return render(request,'blog/post.html',
                 context={
                    'post':post,
                    'showFullText':showFullText, 
                    'comments':comments})
```

В шаблоне будет как-то так:

```
{% if showFullText %}
   post.text
{% else %}
   {{ post.text|truncatechars:100 }}
{% endif %}
```

Ссылку нужно генерировать используя тег [url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#url) так то так:

```
<a href="{% url 'post_url_name' post.id %}?showFullText=true">View full text</a>
```

Вместо `post_url_name` нужно указать имя, которое для view использовано в urlconf

Comment: Ничего не понял на самом деле.

Comment: Ну если разобрать по полочкам: Добавьте во view, которое ответственно за показ страницы с текстом - у меня это класс Post. Допустим я добавлю параметр showFullText,но что ему присваивать? Допустим я присвою ему какое-то значение(если вы ответите потому что в интернете ничего не нашел) и потом как это дело проверять(я про "Если параметр не передан, то считайте, что он False и тогда делайте обрезание текста")Дальше,обрезание текста где?В шаблоне или во view  как-то сделать?В какой ссылке генерировать URL.Обьясните пожалуйста и привидите примеры если вам не трудно,а то не работал с этим. Спасибо!

Comment: Добавил в вопрос.

Comment: у меня как-то не так работает ссылка. Поставил нужное имя,но почему-то ссылка отправляет меня на статью с другим id

Comment: Я идею только подал как решить  описанную  проблему с обрезанием по условию, я не вижу полной картины. Как у вас называются поля, как у вас сконфигурирован urlconf и т.д. Какие-то вещи (например, как генерировать ссылки корректно) нужно поискать. Думаю есть ответы тут на сайте.

Comment: Ну ладно,тут я уже сам разберусь. Огромное спасибо вам за помощь!